# Enum in RIA Services - "NotFound"

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, ria

I am using enum as an input parameter for a RIA Service method.

When the enum value is the first enum value, all is ok, if I choose another value, I receive:

```
The remote server returned an error: NotFound.

at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state) 
at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult) 
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult result)
```

Fiddler shows:

```
    HTTP/1.1 504 Fiddler - Receive Failure 
Content-Type: text/html 
Connection: close     
ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a response for this request.
```

My enum is:

```
[DataContract]
    public enum DataRangeType
    {
        [EnumMember]
        Records = 0,

        [EnumMember]
        Hours,

        [EnumMember]
        Days,

        [EnumMember]
        Months
    }
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Could you implement the Silverlight fault behavior (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee844556(VS.95).aspx) to see what the error actually is?

Comment: I didn't find how to make it for RIA Services.

Comment: **Is a copy of the enum being created correctly in the generated RIA services client-side file?** (check in the hidden generated_code folder in your client app/library). I found a weird bug where comments and spacing could effect the generation of enums.

Comment: in that case, can you provide an example of the RIA method that is causing the problem?

Comment: @INs - Can you show the code for the DomainService? I had similar problems with enums and the root cause was my Linq expression.